# How to solve Level 17 in Eufloria?

Tags: eufloria

My problem is not how to survive, I even one time got all planets cleaned from red, but the black attacked my planets and died. I'm really frustrated, please tell me what is the trick.

Comment: Your problem is how to attack successfully then? More details would be great

Comment: The problem is, i have to defend the black ones.
But sadly, they are fighting against me. Defeating them would be no problem but protecting them is hard as they are defeating themselves by attacking all planets around them.
I even took a watch, since the missions said, "there are 100 of them, keep at least 50 alive for 10 minutes" at around 8 minutes, everything fails...

Comment: Hi Kostronor. Do you mind inserting the content of your comment into the question? That would explain a lot about your problem and where exactly you have it.

Answer (score 3):

I found this to be a challenge where it's best to just get out of their way -- as soon as they attack a world of yours, evacuate that world and let the greys have it.